# Element shared transition works however multiple elements shared does not [Android]

Tags: android, animation, kotlin, transition

I am following from https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity.html to create a transition between a textView and a View when switching activities from a button.

Code for the button:

```js
 btnStart.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, FactsActivity::class.java)
            val options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this,
                UtilPair.create(shapeTop, "transitionShape"),
                UtilPair.create(israelFacts, "textTransition"))
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
        }
```

Everything works fine when I remove the second UtilPar.create, however when both are there, the makeSceneTransitionAnimation has an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Comment: Tried your code and i dont get any errors. In which line does this error shows up on you?

Comment: It shows on the line with the makeSceneTransitionAnimation. It is underlined red with the error i stated above. Still exists :(

Comment: You might be importing the wrong ActivityOptions class or maybe you should try the ActivityOptionsCompat.

Comment: I'll check the imports, however I have tried ActivityOptionsCompat. It's weird since I'm getting the code straight from the developer Android website.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and it seems as though getting all the imports lined up was the issue in my case.  Here's code that works for me with the imports.

```
import androidx.core.util.Pair
import androidx.core.app.ActivityOptionsCompat
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat

   
val intent = Intent(activity, SecondActivity::class.java)
val pair1 = Pair.create<View, String>(view1, "string1")
val pair2 = Pair.create<View, String>(view2, "string2")
val options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, pair1, pair2)
ActivityCompat.startActivity(activity, intent, options.toBundle())
```